# How I can render new field in jquery/rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with rendering an element in jquery/rails.

I would like to do something like this:

When a user clicks on the button "+", another field with select ingredient should be rendered below the default field (because a drink can have a lot of ingredients, and I don't want to specify the amount).

I can't figure it out, so I have to ask for help.

**views/drinks/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @drink do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, class:'form-control' %><br />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'}, class:'form-control' %><br /><br />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group", id: "add-ingredients">
    <%= f.label :ingredient %><br />
    <%= f.select :ingredient_id, Ingredient.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select Few'}, class:'form-control' %><%= f.button "+", class:'btn btn-primary', id: 'btn-ingredients' %><br />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :preparation %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :preparation, class:'form-control'%><br />
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", class:'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", drinks_path, class:'btn btn-default' %>

<% end %>
```

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn-ingredients').click(function(){
    $('#add-ingredients').append('<%= render("form-group") %>');
  });
});
```

I was trying a lot of times and it could be something really easy, but I'm a newbie and haven't got other ideas.

Comment: you may want to give something like https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon a try

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do that in some ways, I just wanna say that manipulating directly the DOM many times is an anti-pattern. Nowadays you have frameworks as React/Redux or ClojureScript that handle the global state and re-render the DOM automatically when the global state "ingredients" is changed.

Maybe not now, but keep it in mind. Handle the state in a "Single Page Application" is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

`application.js` is a static file which is not pre-processed by a ERB-processor, for example. It goes to user's browser as it is, and when executed on client side this code:

```
$('#add-ingredients').append('<%= render("form-group") %>');
```

produces a JS error.

To make it work you need to "unwrap" call of `render("form-group")` into HTML code. For example:

```
$('#add-ingredients').append('<div class="form-group">...</div>');
```

Also please note that [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) actually appends newly created element to the end of element, not AFTER it. So after that call new 'form-group' element will be added to the end of '#add-ingredients' content, which may be undesirable since it has class 'form-group' too.